# Using other methods on a structure inside a `for` loop over an iterator which can mutate this structure

Tags: pointers, iterator, rust

I have something like the following methods on a structure:

```
impl<'a> SomeStructure<'a> {
    // I need &'a mut because the iterator may mutate SomeStructure
    fn iter<'a>(&'a mut self) -> SomeIterator<'a> {
        SomeIterator { object: self }
    }

    fn test_something(&self) -> bool {
        self.some_field < 0
    }

}
```

And then I want to use them like that:

```
impl<'a> SomeTrait for &'a mut SomeStructure<'a> {
    fn do_something(self) {
        for e in self.iter() {
            ...
            if self.test_something() {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, Rust does not allow it (I've fixed error messages so they refer to the sample code above):

```
io/convert_io.rs:119:17: 119:22 error: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
io/convert_io.rs:119             if self.test_something() {
                                    ^~~~~
io/convert_io.rs:117:18: 117:23 note: previous borrow of `*self` occurs here
io/convert_io.rs:117         for e in self.iter() {
                                      ^~~~~
```

But I do not see how immutable borrowing inside `self.test_something()` call can interfere with creating an iterator earlier, even if the iterator does mutate original object.

Could you please explain what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this really what Rust looks like? Yikes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly bug [#8372](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/8372) caused by the minimum-that-works implementation of the current `for`. It is implemented as a macro such that

```
for pattern in iterator { body }
```

expands to (you can see this by running `rustc --pretty expanded foo.rs`)

```
{
    let it = &mut iterator;
    loop {
        match it.next() {
            None => break,
            Some(pattern) => { body }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the `&mut iterator` borrow, which stops `iterator` being used directly while `it` is in scope. You can normally work around this by manually writing the expansion yourself:

```
impl<'a> SomeTrait for &'a mut SomeStructure<'a> {
    fn do_something(self) {
        let mut it = self.iter();
        loop {
            match it.next() {
                None => break
                Some(e) => {
                    if self.test_something() {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That said... this may not actually work in this case if `self.iter()` borrows `self` (especially if `test_something` takes `&mut self`, since the compiler has to disallow mutation or the iterator could be invalidated).

If you were to add a `.view_creator()` method to the return of `self.iter()` (assuming you have a reference to `self` in the `self.iter()` type) then `it.view_creator().test_something()` would work (with the manually unwrapped for loop).

(FWIW, it's a little peculiar to have a trait taking `self` and implementing it on `&mut Thing` rather than taking `&mut self` and implementing it straight on `Thing`; although there *are* good reasons for it sometimes.)

Comment: Yes, I have tried to unwrap the loop manually, and it didn't work. BTW, it seems that you have given wrong bug id :) And yes, there is a reason why I'm implementing the trait like this. You can see from the example code that `SomeTrait` does not have any lifetime parameters, but `SomeStructure` has, and there are also methods on `SomeStructure` that take `&'a` pointer. But you cannot define trait methods which take `&'a [mut] self`, and without this it is impossible to call corresponding methods on `SomeStructure`.

Comment: Also thank you for the suggestion. I'll give it a try. It is rather sad that it is impossible to do rather sane things in Rust (hopefully, impossible to do *yet*).

Comment: And I think you actually meant `match it.next()` in `for` loop expansion :)

Comment: *rather sane things in Rust* In general it's not sane; and it's hard for the compiler to distinguish this (probably) sensible situation from other actually invalid situations (where one is taking an immutable `&` borrow and a `&mut` borrow, and invalidating the first by making a modification through the `&mut` one.) You can declare trait methods like `fn foo<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a ReturnValue`, fwiw, but, as you say, this doesn't always work.

Comment: (and you are correct about both of my mistakes, my apologies. (Fixed)) In any case, I think doing `it.object.test_something()` should work ok.

Comment: Indeed, it is working, just have tested it. Thank you very much again!